# Add font to drop down on SharePoint online

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online

Is it possible to add a font like Arial to the list of available fonts when editing a wiki?

we have SharePoint online so we don't have access to any back-end folders.

Comment: this suggests it is possible in 2010. you can try the same approach. http://santhoshkumar.wordpress.com/2012/01/16/add-a-new-font-to-sharepoint-2010/

Answer (score 4):

I followed this example: https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/pages/use-font-face-in-rich-text-editor-of-sharepoint-2010.aspx

It worked for me in our O365 site collection with the only exception that I had to bump up the class to 15.

```
.ms-rteFontFace-15
{  
    -ms-name: "Bangers";  
   font-family: "Bangers", arial, helvetica, sans-serif;  
}
```